# xcode is building an old version of my app (react-native)

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

#### My Problem :

i recently (automatically) upgrade xcode to v14.
I have for a client a react-native app which is on 0.63.3

The problem is that when i build, the build is on a old version (2.4.4 and now i am on 2.5.0). 
When i launch my app though the terminal, so with :
`npx react-native run-ios --scheme=myApp-staging --simulator='iPhone 12 Pro'`

it works as expected : i am on v2.5.0 on the iPhone 12 Pro simulator.

##### What i tried and that didn't worked :

- Clean build
- Delete `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` content
- Send a Testflight

So after all that actions, I suspect the new version of xcode... i am not sure.

---

Do you have any suggestion ? Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 3):

Since xcode 14, i have to manually build the app before launching it on a device.
So i have to add this script to my package.json

```json
"build:ios": "npx react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios' --assets-dest='ios'",
```